# Which Java client supports sharding + pubsub for Redis?

Tags: redis

Is there a Java client that supports sharding and pubsub for Redis? I looked at jedis and it seems like it lacks that support.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR**

1. Jedis does support pub/sub, I in fact use it.
2. Clustering is a Redis feature for which Jedis has initial support

**Jedis Pub/Sub**

Please check the [jedis pub/sub docs](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage#publishsubscribe) for an extended reference. As simple example you try this out:

```
class MyListener extends JedisPubSub {
        public void onMessage(String channel, String message) {
        }

        public void onSubscribe(String channel, int subscribedChannels) {
        }

        public void onUnsubscribe(String channel, int subscribedChannels) {
        }

        public void onPSubscribe(String pattern, int subscribedChannels) {
        }

        public void onPUnsubscribe(String pattern, int subscribedChannels) {
        }

        public void onPMessage(String pattern, String channel,
            String message) {
        }
}

MyListener l = new MyListener();

jedis.subscribe(l, "foo");
```

**Clustering**

For clustering example first all of it's a good idea to read the [redis cluster tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) to understand if this matches your needs.

Jedis provides an intial API to clustering, but since the Redis feature itself work in progress, this might change in time:

```
Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
//Jedis Cluster will attempt to discover cluster nodes automatically
jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("127.0.0.1", 7379));
JedisCluster jc = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes);
jc.set("foo", "bar");
String value = jc.get("foo");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the sharded jedis client doesn't support pubsub right? I am more interested in getting a recommendation for sharded jedis/redis(java) client that would support pubsub

Answer (score 2):

Two tricky ways to use Jedis cluster to implement pubsub feature.

1. Create a cluster and randomly get two nodes from it. One is used to pub and one is used to sub. the constraint is we don't know when the nodes will down and we have to get check pub/sub connections periodically for their availability and get new ones from cluster nodes.

```
  //create cluster
  HashSet<HostAndPort> node = new HashSet<>();
  node.add(new HostAndPort("127.0.0.1", 7000));
  final JedisClusterPubSub cluster = new JedisClusterPubSub(node);

  //get all nodes
  Map<String, JedisPool> nodes = cluster.getClusterNodes();

  //pick two nodes from the cluster
  final JedisPool pool = nodes.values().iterator().next();
  final JedisPool pool2 = nodes.values().iterator().next();

  // publish 
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

      try {
        while (true) {
          Thread.sleep(3000);
          pool.getResource().publish("channel", "message");
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }).start();

  //subscribe
  pool2.getResource().subscribe(new RequestListener(), "channel");
```

2. Hack the JedisClusterPubSub, extends it and implement the pub/sub option. this is unsafe way.

```
public class JedisClusterPubSub extends JedisCluster{
  public JedisClusterPubSub(Set<HostAndPort> nodes) {
    super(nodes);
  }

  public void subscribe(final JedisPubSub pubSub, final String ... channels){
    try {
      Field fieldCH = JedisCluster.class.getDeclaredField("connectionHandler");
      fieldCH.setAccessible(true);
      JedisClusterConnectionHandler connectionHandler = (JedisClusterConnectionHandler)fieldCH.get(this);

      Field fieldMR = JedisCluster.class.getDeclaredField("maxRedirections");
      fieldMR.setAccessible(true);

      int maxRedirections = (int)fieldMR.get(this);

      new JedisClusterCommand<Void>(connectionHandler, maxRedirections) {
        @Override
        public Void execute(Jedis connection) {
          connection.subscribe(pubSub, channels);
          return null;
        }
      }.run("meaningless");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void publish(final String channel, final String message){
    try {
      Field fieldCH = JedisCluster.class.getDeclaredField("connectionHandler");
      fieldCH.setAccessible(true);
      JedisClusterConnectionHandler connectionHandler = (JedisClusterConnectionHandler)fieldCH.get(this);

      Field fieldMR = JedisCluster.class.getDeclaredField("maxRedirections");
      fieldMR.setAccessible(true);

      int maxRedirections = (int)fieldMR.get(this);

      new JedisClusterCommand<Void>(connectionHandler, maxRedirections) {
        @Override
        public Void execute(Jedis connection) {
          connection.publish(channel, message);
          return null;
        }
      }.run("meaningless");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at redisson:

https://github.com/mrniko/redisson

It is not vanilla use of redis, more like a framework on it. It does support clustering.
Jedis also does support Pub/Sub.